# Join two access table into one

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

Can someone help me to write a query that will join two table into one. I tried the following but I get error:

> "No value given for one or more required parameters."

```
Dim CmdStr As String = "SELECT  col1, col2 FROM table1 UNION SELECT  col1,col2 FROM table2"
```

Comment: What does your table structure look like? Your SQL looks correct, but most likely col1 or col2 doesn't exist in one of the tables. Also, please include ALL the relevant code. Help us to help you, please.

Comment: What's your programming environment? In VBA, you certainly can't assign the value of a variable in the same line you declare it.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear. [UNION](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_%28SQL%29) and [JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) are completely different things. We'll need more detail on how your tables look and what result you desire.

If you have e.g.

```
table1             table2
| col1 | col2 |    | col1 | col2 |
|------|------|    |------|------|
|   1  |   4  |    |   5  |   7  |
```

Result for UNION (only possible if table1 and table2 have the same data types)

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM table1
UNION
SELECT col1, col2 FROM table2

|------|------|
|   1  |   4  |
|   5  |   7  |
```

Result for JOIN

```
SELECT t1.col1, t1.col2, t2.col1, t2.col2
FROM table1 t1 CROSS JOIN table2 t2 

|t1.col1|t1.col2|t2.col1|t2.col2|
|-------|-------|-------|-------|
|   1   |   4   |   5   |   7   |
```

further more there are various different kind of *outer* and *inner JOINS*
see an overview [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming by `join` you do not mean the usual meaning of the term in sql context, which you should if you are asking a sql question, and by assuming you want to `COMBINE` results from the two tables, the sql you have written is correct if the tables `Table1` and `Table2` exist in the database and they both have col1 and col2. Take into account that the `UNION` operator selects only distinct values by default, whereas `UNION ALL` will also select duplicates. But the error you are having:
`"No value given for one or more required parameters."`
does not seem to be a sql error. it seems to be raised by your programming code, where you fill you dataset/recordset most probably. If more code is posted a better answer can be provided.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to share the rest of your code, it looks like you're using something like this

```
Dim cmd as ADODB.command
Dim CmdStr As String = "SELECT col1, col2 FROM table1 UNION SELECT col1,col2 FROM table2"

cmd.CommandText = cmdStr
```

give us more of your code, maybe we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much ,all of you,I am absolate new but I feel like i can get it to work now .heres the code i am using

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim con As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\deletedb.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=1")
        Dim CmdStr As String = "SELECT  col1, col2 FROM table1 UNION SELECT  col1,col2 FROM table2"        
        con.Open()
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(CmdStr, con)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()
        MsgBox("Done")
    End Sub
```

Comment: Ticks ( ` ) stop working as markup symbols when you split the code into paragraphs (i.e. when you put empty lines in-between). In such cases format it as a code block instead (using the `{}` button or indenting all the lines of code by at least 4 spaces).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is your data source string.  By default access has a user called Admin with a blank password.  Unless you have added security to the database, the connection string should be

```
"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\deletedb.accdb;User ID=Admin;Password="
```